# Remove citation from Latex

Tags: latex, citations, miktex

I am trying to edit a a paper in Latex. But it make some problems in Reference section. I deleted three citation from reference file and remove citation name Like, \cite{X...} from the paper content. But still the citation are showed in the original pdf file. I need a suggestion, what would be solution or better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `*.log` files: you should understand better what's going on. However, citations handling has several steps (simplified version):

1. `latex file.tex` outputs a `file.aux` with the citations
2. `bibtex file.tex` outputs a `file.bbl` with the references
3. one more (or even more) `latex file.tex` is needed to get the article with both references and citations

The complete flow (taken from Goosens, Mittelbach, and Samarin (1994) The LaTeX Companion, Figure 12.1, p. 375) is: [[image: (http://www.zapata.org/stuart/latex/bibtex_process.jpg)]]

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information. I did it. The problem was happening for bbl and aux file. I edit it afterwords the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and I resolved it by deleting all the build generated files, i.e. `*.aux`, `*.log` etc, and rebuilding the `.tex` file.